# Extend two objects with no deep copy but without overwrite array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've two objects and I would like to join in one just by overwriting the same values.

```
var objOne = { current: 1, sort: { 'foo' : 'bar' }, search: [ { name: 'a', value: 1 }, { name: 'b', value: 2 } ] };
var objTwo = { sort: { 'john' : 'doe' }, search: [ { name: 'a', value: 3 } ] };
```

I tried with $.extends without deep copy and works well for all elements except for array objects.

```
var objAll = $.extend( {}, objOne, objTwo );

objAll -> { current: 1, sort: { 'john' : 'doe' }, search: [{ name: 'a', value: 3 }] };
```

My goal would be to get this

```
objAll -> { current: 1, sort: { 'john' : 'doe' }, search: [{ name: 'a', value: 3 },{ name: 'b', value: 2 }] };
```

Overwrite only the array of objects with the same name.

How can I do this? thanks

Comment: create an object with 2 foreach

Comment: how do you know, which one to update in the array?

Comment: The last overwrite the previous (like $extend)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using ES6 Proxies, using set trap in the handler.

```
var objOne = {    current: 1,    sort: { 'foo' : 'bar' },    search: [ { name: 'a', value: 1 }, { name: 'b', value: 2 } ]  };

var proxy = new Proxy(objOne, {
         set(trapTarget, key, value, receiver) {
              // not altering the existing array properties
              if (trapTarget.hasOwnProperty(key) && Array.isArray(trapTarget[key])) {

                return Reflect.set(trapTarget, key, trapTarget[key], receiver)  
              } 

              return Reflect.set(trapTarget, key, value, receiver);

         } });

Object.assign(proxy,{ sort: { 'john' : 'doe' }, search: [ { name: 'a', value: 3 } ] });

console.log(objOne);
```

JsFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/8n3c8hs0/

Comment: Unfortunately works for sort object but not for array search. In fact it returns the search: [{name: 'a', value: 1}, {name: 'b', value: 2}] and not search: [{name: 'a', value: 3}, {name: 'b', value: 2}]